# ExpressJS and Mongoose query scope problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to write a piece of code :

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let listElevators = [];
  await Building.findById(req.body.id).then((building) => {
    building.Equipement.forEach(async (e) => {
      await Elevator.findById(e).then((rzlt) => {
        let bool = false;
        rzlt.Equipement_elevator.forEach((equip) => {
          if (equip.Year == req.body.year) {
            bool = true;
          }
        });
        if (bool) {
          listElevators.push(e);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  res.status(200).json(listElevators);
});
```

the problem is that "listElevators" is always empty when i return it, but if i console log right after the "if (bool)", the variable is not empty.

Do you guys please know where's the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: try for loop instead of forEach loop.

Comment: Your code doesn't wait for async execution in this line: `building.Equipement.forEach(async (e) => {`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your function like this.

A few things to notice

- I've removed all the `.then`, they're not needed anymore since, you have `async/await`
- I've added await outside of first `forEach` to make sure that res.status() gets called when everything inside the loop has finished
- Removed the `if (bool)` and moved the logic directly to the first `if`

  ```
  router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   let listElevators = [];
   try {
     const building = await Building.findById(req.body.id);
     await building.Equipement.forEach(async e => {
       const rzlt = await Elevator.findById(e);

       rzlt.Equipement_elevator.forEach(equip => {
       if (equip.Year == req.body.year) {
         listElevators.push(e);
       }
    });
  });

   res.status(200).json(listElevators);
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `async` `await` with `.then` `.catch`, your code is not clean

use `for of` instead of first `forEach`

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let listElevators = [];
        let building = await Building.findById(req.body.id);
        for (let e of building){
           let rzlt =  await Elevator.findById(e);
           let bool = false;
           rzlt.Equipement_elevator.forEach((equip) => {
            if (equip.Year == req.body.year) {
              bool = true;
            }
          });
          if (bool) {
            listElevators.push(e);
          }
        }
        res.status(200).json(listElevators);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  });
```